# php unique rand() inside set of numbers

Tags: php

I am trying to put a load of images in a random order using php this is what I have tried

```
for ($i=47; $i < 54; $i++) {
            echo "<img width='205' src='IMG_03";
            echo rand(47,53);
            echo ".jpeg' alt=''>";  
}
```

But this code includes duplicates how could I do this without having the same random number between 47 and 53 twice?

Comment: `$values = range(47,53); shuffle($values);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$numbers = range(47, 54);
shuffle($numbers);

foreach($numbers as $n) {
    echo '<img src="IMG_03'.$n.'.jpg" alt="" />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$array = range(47, 53);
shuffle($array);

foreach ($array as $a) {
    echo "<img width='205' src='IMG_03";
    echo $a;
    echo ".jpeg' alt=''>";  
}
```

[range()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) creates an array of numbers between the given values: 47, 48, ..., 53

[shuffle()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) puts it in random order

Answer (score 0):

Use the `shuffle` method

```
$arr = array(47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53);

shuffle($arr);

while($element = array_pop($arr)){
    echo "<img width='205' src='IMG_03";
    echo $element;
    echo ".jpeg' alt=''>";  
}
```